# java2wsdl (axis2) usage

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm trying to use `java2wsdl` to generate a document literal wsdl for `JiraSoapServiceImpl`. However it seems that no matter what usage I use, I got a ClassNotFoundException.

```
java2wsdl -cp . -cn com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.JiraSoapServiceImpl
```

The files are located next to the bat file.

https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/source/browse/JRPC/trunk/rpc-jira-plugin/src/main/java/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.JiraSoapServiceImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLUtils.namespaceFromClassName(Java2WSDLUtils.java:65)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLUtils.schemaNamespaceFromClassName(Java2WSDLUtils.java:84)
        at org.apache.ws.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLBuilder.getSchemaTargetNamespace(Java2WSDLBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.ws.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLBuilder.generateWSDL(Java2WSDLBuilder.java:212)
        at org.apache.ws.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLCodegenEngine.generate(Java2WSDLCodegenEngine.java:59)
        at org.apache.ws.java2wsdl.Java2WSDL.main(Java2WSDL.java:32)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception? Which class is not found?

Comment: your `cp` option set to `.` is the problem. have it include the package your class resides in.

Comment: i get the same exception with a path in there. >java2wsdl -cp C:\jira\rpc\soap -cn com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.JiraSoapServiceImpl

Comment: i'm in the directory with java2wsdl in it so i should reference the path as above too?

Comment: You should probably read [Understanding the class path and package names](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#Understanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java2wsdl -cp . -cn
>   com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.JiraSoapServiceImpl
>   The files are located next to the bat
>   file.

This class should be in ./com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapServiceImpl.class. Is it, or as you said, it is "next to bat file", i.e. ./JiraSoapServiceImpl.class?

And -- just for a case -- it should be *.class, not *.java.

BTW, JIRA has public WSDL, why do you need to generate something from Impl class?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go today. I want to make a document/literal wsdl, rather than the rpc encoded one.

Comment: you may do, no doubt... would JIRA service understand you, though?

Comment: okay, i don't understand why this does not work. C:\com\atlassian\jira\rpc\soap\JiraSoapServiceImpl.class is the actual path. what should i put into java2wsdl?

Comment: getting there! Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/util/ErrorCollection now :|